# How to post utf characters in android with getStreamFromURL?

Tags: android

I send some parameters to server with this way in my android code:

```
String url = "http://" + ip + formPath + "?" + constParameters
                    + "&Username=" + username + "&Password=" + Password
                    + "&ACT=" + action;


InputStream jsonStream = jsonUtil.getStreamFromURL(url, "GET");

String jsonString = jsonUtil.streamToString(jsonStream);
```

but it sends some of my parameters (which are with persian characters) as ? character.

what can i do?
I can't change the way to send parameters(this is the only way that I can send them). thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try URLEncoding the username and password using the [`URLEncoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html)?

```
String encodedUsername = URLEncoder.encode(username, "utf-8");
String encodedPassword = URLEncoder.encode(password, "utf-8");
String url = "http://" + ip + formPath + "?" + constParameters
                    + "&Username=" + encodedUsername + "&Password=" + encodedPassword
                    + "&ACT=" + action;
```